# In a 2-state Markov chain, what is probability that $\texttt{State-2}$ has been picked exactly $k$ number of times out of $n$ timestep

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

I think the question I am asking might already be derived, but I could not find it. So this is how it goes, suppose I have a 2-state Markov chain having states $\texttt{State-1}$ and $\texttt{State-2}$. The transition matrix of this 2-state Markov chain is as
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12}\\
p_{21} & p_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$
We assume that Markov chain always starts in $\texttt{State-1}$.
I want to find the probability that $\texttt{State-1}$ or $\texttt{State-2}$ has been picked exactly $k$ number of times out of $n$ timesteps.

Approach till now,

Suppose $n=2$, In $n=0$, I am in $\texttt{State-1}$, what is the probability I will get $\texttt{State-2}$ exactly $1$ time only, the possible walks would be,
$$\underbrace{\texttt{State-1}}_{n=0} \rightarrow \underbrace{\texttt{State-1}}_{n=1} \rightarrow \underbrace{\texttt{State-2}}_{n=2} \quad\text{and}\quad \underbrace{\texttt{State-1}}_{n=0} \rightarrow \underbrace{\texttt{State-2}}_{n=1} \rightarrow \underbrace{\texttt{State-1}}_{n=2}$$
Therefore the probability of such event would be
$$P(X_1=1|X_0=1)\times P(X_2=2|X_1=1) + P(X_1=2|X_0=1)\times P(X_2=1|X_1=2)$$
Likewise for $n=4$, what is the probability I will get $\texttt{State-2}$ exactly $2$ times only, the possible walks would be,
$$\underbrace{1}_{n=1},\underbrace{1}_{n=2},\underbrace{2}_{n=3},\underbrace{2}_{n=4}\\
1,2,2,1\\
2,2,1,1\\
1,2,1,2\\
2,1,2,1\\
2,1,1,2$$

Here in $n=0$ $\texttt{State-1}$ is always picked. There are $\binom{4}{2}$ possible combinations. I idea is not simple as to use binomial distribution, but because the depending upon which state your are, probabilities changes. If anyone has an idea how to solve this for a generalized $k$ and $n$, please help me.